# "Null reference Exception" occurring when checking the condition while adding the record into a list in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to add a record into the "Links" list in sharepoint 2010. 
I want to put a validation for adding item. I written like this.
[image]

I am trying to stop to enter any link containing google keyword. Is there any thing wrong in the following code. I am doing for my practice. 
I think in the image code is not appearing clearly. I written down here.

```
if (properties.AfterProperties["vti_url"].ToString().Contains("google"))
           {
               properties.ErrorMessage = "You should not enter the google";
                 properties.Cancel = true;
           }
```

After adding `properties.AfterProperties["URL"].ToString().Contains("google")` it is running fine. But my error page is not looking good. here is the screen shot. What to do for this problem.
[image]

Comment: Have you checked if `properties.AfterProperties["vti_url"]` returns `null`?

Answer (score 1):

I would take a wild guess and say `properties.AfterProperties["vti_url"]` is `null`, because there is no field called "vti_url" ... have you tried:

```
properties.AfterProperties["URL"]
```

Comment: Hello Hinek.. thanks for your answer. I think it is close to work. Please see my edited question.

Comment: Hi, for your new error, this might help: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/28495/event-reciever-custom-error-message-page-sharepoint-list-2010

Comment: In that link, the accepted answer is revert back the changes made to web.config file. But i didn't made any changes to web.config file. The property values are same only

Comment: The accepted answer is to revert it, right. Maybe you haven't changed your web.config, but someone (or some program) has, because I see the full Exception and StackTrace in your screenshot ... you have to set custom errors mode to of: http://blogit.create.pt/blogs/miguelisidoro/archive/2007/11/18/SharePoint-2007-Debugging-_1320_-Show-Error-Messages--.aspx

Comment: CHeck this link out and look at your web config http://dobrzanski.net/2008/09/19/aspx-running-on-sharepoint-display-stack-trace/

Answer (score 1):

`enter code here`The comment Hinek mentioned is more than likely correct

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Checks the object to see if it's null, if it isn't it will return the string value of the object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">(object) The object you want to check.</param>
    /// <returns>(string) The string value of the object.</returns>
    public static string CheckForNullValue(object value)
    {
        string tmpValue = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
                {
                    tmpValue = value.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Error.Log("Failed to check for null value Value passed in" + value, exc, Error.ErrorType_Error);
            throw exc;
        }
        return tmpValue;
    }

string url = CheckForNullValue(properties.AfterProperties["vti_url"])


if (url.Contains("Google"))   
       {   
           properties.ErrorMessage = "You should not enter the google";   
             properties.Cancel = true;   
       }
```

Hope this helps